# p2 plugins folder auto discovery

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2

In [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Getting_Started) guide for p2, it is mentioned that:

> The file bundles.info contains a list of all the plug-ins installed in the current system. On startup, all the plug-ins listed in this file are given to OSGi as the exact set of plug-ins to run with.
>
> **Any extra plug-ins in the plugins directory or elsewhere are ignored.**

But right below, it is also mentioned that:

> The new dropins folder is where you can drop in extra plug-ins if you don't want to use the p2 user interface. See the dropins section for more details. For backwards compatibility, **p2 will also detect extra plug-ins dropped into the plugins directory, and install any discovered bundles into the system.**

The info seems to be contradictory? So which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. The first one ist referencing the installation which is covered inside the bundles.info file. 
The dropins folder is parallel to the installation plugins folder. Plugins stored inside this folder will be dynamically installed and started during   Eclipse startup. So you can add bundles by storing them inside the dropins folder. Mind that there are different layouts supported [Dropins Layouts](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html)

Comment: Both of the quotes refer to the "plugins" folder, not the "dropins" folder

Comment: If you want to add plugins to your eclipse installation put them in the dropins folder. They will be auto-discovered from there.

Comment: I know that, however I'm asking about the quotes which refer to the "plugins" folder, not the "dropins" folder.

Comment: I'm not the author of the page, but I assume that it is referring to a plugins folder inside a dropins folder layout and not the Eclipse Installation plugins folder.